# How to cache CollectionViewCell images that is part of custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

So, I have this news feed structure. Every news block is a custom `UITableViewCell`. Now, every custom cell has a `CollectionView` that shows images.

[image]

The problem is that when scrolling, and news cell (news block) comes out visible, the `CollectionView` is reloading - every time cell shows up. I'm trying to find the way to cache those images on the main `ViewController` side.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid implementing your own cache/disk/memory handlers for this kind of job I strongly recommend either AFNetworking or SDWebImage that handle it all for you.

An example of SDWebImage on how to set an image and its cache:

```
[imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

This handles all the cache/disk/memory for you automatically.

Here is example of how you handle cache with SDWebImage:

// Set memory size limit (check with older devices to avoid memory errors when setting it to high value.)

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] setMaxMemoryCost:****];
```

// Clear disk cache

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearDiskOnCompletion:^{
}];
```

// Clear memory cache

```
[[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];
```

I would stay away from NSUserDefaults or the above mentioned example setting the images to dictionary or arrays to avoid memory errors and app crashes/performance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cache your UIImage instance, so, if you get some pictures from any source, you might write something like below:

```
/* some code before */
UIImage *yourImage = /* Get your UIImage from any available way */
[self.cache setObject:yourImage forKey:@"SomeUniqueID"];
/* some code after */
```

I guess, this code will look greater as a function, which obtains UIImage instance and it's id as parameters.

For my opinion, it's the most common way to store images. If you need a more proficient way without any overheads with third-party frameworks, you can read the documentation about [NSCache](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscache?language=objc).

But in general, you have a lot of different ways how to store your images:

1. Get the image from the disk
2. Get the image from the memory
3. Use one of the variants above, but apart them still use some *lightweight & flexible* frameworks, you can find a lot of on the GitHub.

So, the code I wrote above will just store images into the memory cache.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the idea. Wondering, is NSCache memory works across UIViewControllers (something like NSUserDefault..)?

Comment: @ekashkin NSCache syntax is similar to NSUserDefaults and all objects which should store in cache have to implement NSSecureCoding protocol, like UIImage